# Google new KMLLayer not working with data extracted from custom map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created my google map. Imported markers from google spreadsheet. Shared this map publicly. Export like KMZ. With choosing option "Keep data updated". Then In my JS Application trying to load KML Layer. I am using link that was placed inside downloaded kmz/kml file.
http://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?forcekml=1&mid=zmJT0iVx3pVs.kmPWwDLpv90w&lid=zmJT0iVx3pVs.kenD66KR2z4o

screenshot http://screencloud.net/v/lRjb

My JS code.

```
   var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.988997, 36.225374),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/kml?forcekml=1&mid=zmJT0iVx3pVs.kmPWwDLpv90w&lid=zmJT0iVx3pVs.kenD66KR2z4o');
    kmzLayer.setMap(map);
```

I have no seen any diagnostic in console.

So My Question is: 
1) How to load this data? I need user of "My Map" able to add new places using this spreadsheet/map.
2) I see in these exported kml a lot options(columns) that exist in spreadsheet, but not chosen for description. It is not secure to use this columns. In the reason i want to see just address and title on the map

Comment: When I look at an example of KML, like here ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml ), I see lots of coordinates.  I don't see any coordinates in your file.  Are you sure of your file?  Else ... maybe what you want, is just to some data on your map (not via a kml file); do you have that data in an other format (something that shows coordinates)?

Comment: In this file I have addresses. It is was imported to maps.google.com, https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/edit?hl=en_US&app=mp&mid=zmJT0iVx3pVs.kmPWwDLpv90w then i've just pressed submenu, and pressed http://screencloud.net/v/qHMe Export KML, so it look to be built by google

Comment: How was it imported to "maps.google.com"?  It looks like whatever process you used didn't create a KML file with `<coordinates>` in it.  The addresses will need to be geocoded (translated into coordinates) for the points to display on a Google Maps JavaScript API v3 map.